# Different results between Base64 and MimeUtility

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I am attempting to update a method using Base64OutputStream vs MimeUtility and running into slightly different results.

The original method looks like:

```
private static String encodePassword(String password) {
    MessageDigest algorithm;
    try {
        algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(password.getBytes());
        byte[] encrypted =  algorithm.digest();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream encoder = MimeUtility.encode(out, "base64");

        encoder.write(encrypted);
        encoder.flush();
        return new String(out.toByteArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return "Bad Encryption";
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        return "Bad Encryption";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Bad Encryption";
    }
```

Here is my updated method:

```
private static String encodePassword(String password) {
    MessageDigest algorithm;
    try {
        algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(password.getBytes());
        byte[] encrypted =  algorithm.digest();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream encoder = new Base64OutputStream(out);

        encoder.write(encrypted);
        encoder.flush();
        return new String(out.toByteArray());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return "Bad Encryption";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Bad Encryption";
    }
}
```

The first method returns the correct encryption: "ISMvKXpXpadDiUoOSoAfww=="
the second returns MOST of it -  "ISMvKXpXpadDiUoOSoAf"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: raw base64 and mime encoding using base64 are two different things, hence the different results. Also, this is not 'encryption' and hopefully not a real example of how you plan to store passwords.

Comment: @pvg can you shed light on how i can achieve the same results?

Comment: Don't use two different classes that do two different things? Much easier  and safer - just use bcrypt. http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

Comment: this is part of some legacy awful code that I can't get to run in spring due to that MimeUtility class... not even sure how much will be kept but i could not quite see why I was getting slightly different results.

Comment: Too bad that the catch blocks are unreachable. Otherwise it would become trivial to log into all accounts that get hashed to `Bad Encryption`. Therefore, don't return a string, throw an exception in these impossible cases.

Comment: By the way, dont use `String.getBytes()` without parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html

As the documentation states :

> Note: It is mandatory to close the stream after the last byte has been written to it, otherwise the final padding will be omitted and the resulting data will be incomplete/inconsistent.

You need to close your stream when you are finished writing to it.

The missing `==` is the padding at the end because base 64 works in 3 character chunks.  When you have a length not divisible by 3 you pad the result with one or two `=` characters

Comment: closing this did get me that ending ==, although it also adds a "r/n/" char --  thanks for the tip